# WebService won't update through ServiceReference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, web-services, service-reference

I have two projects in my Visual Studio solution: The one is a *WcfService Application project* and the other one is an ordinary *C# Silverlight project* with a **ServiceReference** to access the Web Service **locally.**

Basically everything works fine except the fact that changes in my Web Service are **not visible** in my SL project:

If i for example modify some attribute in a [DataContract] class of the service' interface, both projects compile well but the when accessing the web service in the SL project i only have the state before the modification.

Viewing the ServiceReference in the VisualStudios ObjectBrowser gives me the same result: **My Web Service without modification.**

I added the ServiceReference to the SL project via the in-built automatic *"Add Service Reference"* function. Everytime i modify the web service i click *"Update Service Reference"* on the Service Reference in the SL project which succeeds but without effect. **Even** a removal of the Service Reference and **adding it again** doesn't show me the web service with the altered attribute.

Maybe it's because i renamed the Service Project a few days ago - I unloaded the service project from the solution, renamed the folders in the file system and added it again as an "existing project" to the solution. Then i renamed the service file (.svc & .svc.cs) and the service interface file. ==> After that everything seems to work still fine except my unrecognized modifications ?! Also when adding a ServiceReference to this service I see the old names of the two files i renamed not the new ones !?

Does anyone has a clue what's going on here ?
Thank you in advance for reading this long question ;)

Comment: This probably sounds like a weird question, but have you tried rebooting your box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve your problem (OK, it's probably not the best solution, even probably the worst one, but I'm sure it'll work) is to do a bunch of cleanup:

- remove from your SL project your service reference
- delete on your file system everything related to the service reference you deleted (i.e. drop related files/folders in SL project
  directory)
- also open your SL csproj (or vbproj) file with notepad and delete the lines that are related to service references (search for
  "Service References" in the file)
- create a new WcfService Application project from scratch, and add what's needed to it (references, files...) so it reflects the
  current WcfService project you have
- delete the old WcfService project
- compile your new WcfService project
- add your new WcfService project as a service reference into your SL project

Okay, you'll lose some time doing this, but it'll work.

Comment: hey thank you for your answer ! :) I've already searched all the files for service related stuff - and now i found out that I obviously have missed one single file: the .svc file contained one line with the old name of my web service project. After renaming this as well my web service reference in the SL project works perfectly!

So I what I was doing from beginning on - renaming and relocating the project by hand did work perfectly - i simply forgot to rename the line mentioned above :)

Comment: @ ken2k: Thank you very much for your effort in answering my question ! :)